# Want to Filter Results into New Tables, by matching key words in R (preferably using data.table)

Tags: r, data.table

I have some data which has a number of customer comments. I want to match these comments to certain key words, and put them each in a new table.

For example, if I have a large data table with three sample comments:

| Customer ID | Comment |
| --- | --- |
| 71223338 | "the staff were really helpful" |
| 11111223 | "the website is great" |
| 22112233 | "the mobile app is poor" |

I want to filter these to three new tables:

1. "Staff"
2. "Website"
3. "App"

I'm struggling to write a code which matches the key words and puts them into new tables.

Hope someone is able to help! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You might try using `lapply` to make a list of data.tables.

```
library(data.table)
variables <- c("Staff","Website","App")
setDT(data)
lapply(variables,function(x)data[grepl(x,Comment,ignore.case = TRUE),])
#[[1]]
#   Customer.ID                       Comment
#1:    71223338 the staff were really helpful
#
#[[2]]
#   Customer.ID                                          Comment
#1:    11111223                             the website is great
#2:    11112223 the Website looks like it was designed by a slob
#
#[[3]]
#   Customer.ID                            Comment
#1:    22112233             the mobile app is poor
#2:    22112234 the mobile Application is horrible
```

Sample Data:

```
data <- structure(list(Customer.ID = c(71223338L, 11111223L, 22112233L, 
22112234L, 11112223L), Comment = c("the staff were really helpful", 
"the website is great", "the mobile app is poor", "the mobile Application is horrible", 
"the Website looks like it was designed by a slob")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: I'd suggest you start using purrr for working with lists (not the answerer, but the OP)  - this  will help you immensely later in the processing of the list of data.tables. https://jennybc.github.io/purrr-tutorial/

Comment: also, you can speed this up using the argument fixed=TRUE in grepl(). If your toy example is close to the real data, and you're not using regex but just matching on text as-is. The operator %flike% from data.table is grepl() just with fixed=TRUE, for readability and shorthand notation.